# mod_rewrite: Rename filenames based on language

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bilingual website both in English and German. Both versions are served from the same root files like `index.php`, `projects.php`, `people.php`, etc.

The English versions are called via

```
http://myexample.com/en/index.php
http://myexample.com/en/projects.php
http://myexample.com/en/people.php
```

The German versions are called via

```
http://myexample.com/de/index.php
http://myexample.com/de/projects.php
http://myexample.com/de/people.php
```

For SEO reasons I like the German filenames to be Germanized:

```
de/projects.php -› projekte.php
de/people.php   -› leute.php
```

Can anybody help out?

Comment: Read about `RewriteMap`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+de/projects\.php
RewriteRule ^ /projekte.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+de/people\.php
RewriteRule ^ /leute.php [L,R]

RewriteRule ^projekte\.php$ /de/projects.php [L]
RewriteRule ^leute\.php$ /de/people.php [L]
```